# How to compress one region of the x-axis of the plot in MATLAB to make the overall graph look relevent?

Tags: matlab, plot, charts

I am trying to plot the comparison of 4 numerical methods using MATLAB and one value is just realy far away on the x-axis and it occupies almost the entire plot, as can be seen in the image [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr8V1.jpg). I want to shrink the red region and stretch the green region so that all the important points in the green region get appropriate attention. How do I do that? The code is also provided. Any help is extremly appreciated.

```
   x1=[12*4 24*8 48*16 96*32 192*64];
   x2=[12*4 19*6 21*7 24*8 28*9];
   x3=[18*6 24*8 33*11 39*13 45*15 51*17];
   x4=[18*6 24*8 33*11 39*13 45*15 51*17];
   
   U1=[7.4207e-02 1.3801e-02 5.5384e-03 1.5280e-03 3.9070e-04];
   U2=[4.6278e-01 5.1786e-02 2.8978e-02 1.0437e-02 1.5375e-03];
   U3=[3.7161e-01 1.2637e-01 1.6715e-02 4.5160e-03 1.3843e-03 6.0238e-04];
   U4=[4.0301e-01 1.3381e-01 1.7245e-02 4.7084e-03 1.4937e-03 6.4130e-04];


  semilogy(x1,U1,'mo-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','c','LineWidth',2);
  hold on
  semilogy(x2,U2,'bd-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','g','LineWidth',2);
  hold on
  semilogy(x3,U3,'ks-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2);
  hold on
  semilogy(x4,U4,'^-', 'MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerEdgeColor','y','LineWidth',2);
 

 xlabel('N','fontsize',20)
 ylabel('L_{\infty}','fontsize',20) 
 legend('HWCM','MQ-MCM', 'IMQ-MCM','HIMQ-MCM');
```

I have tried to solve this problem on chatgpt and google bard. Spent many hours on these sites but could not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [loglog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html) function? The following code snippet gives you a better plot.

```matlab
x1=[12*4 24*8 48*16 96*32 192*64];
x2=[12*4 19*6 21*7 24*8 28*9];
x3=[18*6 24*8 33*11 39*13 45*15 51*17];
x4=[18*6 24*8 33*11 39*13 45*15 51*17];

U1=[7.4207e-02 1.3801e-02 5.5384e-03 1.5280e-03 3.9070e-04];
U2=[4.6278e-01 5.1786e-02 2.8978e-02 1.0437e-02 1.5375e-03];
U3=[3.7161e-01 1.2637e-01 1.6715e-02 4.5160e-03 1.3843e-03 6.0238e-04];
U4=[4.0301e-01 1.3381e-01 1.7245e-02 4.7084e-03 1.4937e-03 6.4130e-04];


loglog(x1,U1,'mo-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','c','LineWidth',2);
hold on
loglog(x2,U2,'bd-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','g','LineWidth',2);
hold on
loglog(x3,U3,'ks-', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerEdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2);
hold on
loglog(x4,U4,'^-', 'MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerEdgeColor','y','LineWidth',2);


xlabel('N','fontsize',20)
ylabel('L_{\infty}','fontsize',20) 
legend('HWCM','MQ-MCM', 'IMQ-MCM','HIMQ-MCM');
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know what is best for Fahim, I also like the schedule that you have proposed to @JimmyHu

Answer (score -1):

### Just use two X scales...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [12*4, 24*8, 48*16, 96*32, 192*64]
x2 = [12*4, 19*6, 21*7, 24*8, 28*9]
x3 = [18*6, 24*8, 33*11, 39*13, 45*15, 51*17]
x4 = [18*6, 24*8, 33*11, 39*13, 45*15, 51*17]
U1 = [7.4207e-02, 1.3801e-02, 5.5384e-03, 1.5280e-03, 3.9070e-04]
U2 = [4.6278e-01, 5.1786e-02, 2.8978e-02, 1.0437e-02, 1.5375e-03]
U3 = [3.7161e-01, 1.2637e-01, 1.6715e-02, 4.5160e-03, 1.3843e-03, 6.0238e-04]
U4 = [4.0301e-01, 1.3381e-01, 1.7245e-02, 4.7084e-03, 1.4937e-03, 6.4130e-04]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.semilogy(x1, U1, 'mo-', markerfacecolor='b',
             markeredgecolor='c', linewidth=2)
ax1.set_xlabel('N', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel('L_{\infty}', fontsize=20)
plt.legend(['HWCM'], loc="lower left")

ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax2.semilogy(x2, U2, 'bd-', markerfacecolor='b',
             markeredgecolor='g', linewidth=2)
ax2.semilogy(x3, U3, 'ks-', markerfacecolor='b',
             markeredgecolor='r', linewidth=2)
ax2.semilogy(x4, U4, '^-', markerfacecolor='r',
             markeredgecolor='y', linewidth=2)
ax2.set_xlabel('N', fontsize=20)
plt.legend(['MQ-MCM', 'IMQ-MCM', 'HIMQ-MCM'], loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks so much better but I want to plot them on the same scale to make a good comparison. You answer and time is still very much apprciated. Thank you @SVBazuev

Comment: The OP wants an answer in Matlab, but this is Python